# Post a form in Node Js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to post data from a form in node JS and then see the data in console. When i click the button I can see the data in console but the websites starts loading and it doesnt end. The loading circle doesnt stop moving.

```html
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="user[name]">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and this is in my server.js file

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

// Access the parse results as request.body
app.post('/', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body.user.name);
});
```

Comment: Your backend has to send a response, e.g. `response.sendStatus(200)`.

Comment: As you are not returning anything from the route as a response the browser waiting for a response so it is loading. In order to avoid that return as a response something like @jabaa said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend has to send a response, e.g. [`response.sendStatus(200)`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus), otherwise the frontend will wait until it timeouts.

Example:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

// Access the parse results as request.body
app.post('/', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body.user.name);
    response.sendStatus(200);
});
```